# Loop through result of powershell function in batch

Tags: loops, powershell, batch-file, cmd, msbuild

I have powershell function, which return array of pathes to projects in solution.

```
function GetPathToSfProj($rootPath, $solutionName){
   $retPath = Get-Content "$($rootPath)\$($solutionName)" |
     Select-String 'Project\((.*\.sfproj)' |
       ForEach-Object {
         $projectParts = $_ -Split '[,=]' | ForEach-Object { $_.Trim('[ "{}]') };
         New-Object PSObject -Property @{
           File = $projectParts[2];
         }
       }

   return $retPath.File;
}
```

I try to execute it from batch file and build package using msBuild.

```
FOR /F "delims=" %%i IN ('"powershell . ".\GetSfProjPath.ps1 GetPathToSfProj -rootPath "%ProjectLocationPath%" -solutionName "%SolutionName%""; "') DO (
   SET VAL=%%i
   call %MSBuildPath%\MSBuild.exe %VAL% /t:package /p:Configuration=Debug
)
```

But in loop variable always are NULL

If I test powershell function separatelly, it returns correct result. So problem in batch.

Comment: You have to use delayed expansion - put `setlocal enableDelayedexpansion` on the 2nd line. and change `.exe %VAL%` to `.exe !VAL!`

Comment: Don't use the interim variable `VAL`, use `%%i` (or rather `"%%~i"`) immediately; also quote path to `MSBuild.exe`; and you don't need `call` to run an `.exe` file...

Comment: @aschipfl Ohh I see.

Comment: Try to execute the PowerShell command line without the `for /F` loop: what do you get then?

Comment: Since you use Powershell already, why don't you use Powershell as well to call msbuild instead of relying on cmd.exe?

Comment: @stijn, now I'm working on it :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I strongly recommend against mixing script languages when there is no need to do so. Simply parametrize your PowerShell script and pipe the output of your function to a `ForEach-Object` loop that calls `MSBuild.exe`:

```
[CmdletBinding()]
Param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true]
    [string]$ProjectLocationPath,

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true]
    [string]$SolutionName
)

function GetPathToSfProj($rootPath, $solutionName) {
    Get-Content "${rootPath}\${solutionName}" |
        Select-String 'Project\((.*\.sfproj)' |
        ForEach-Object { ($_ -split '[,=]')[2].Trim('[ "{}]') }
}

GetPathToSfProj -rootPath $ProjectLocationPath -solutionName $SolutionName | ForEach-Object {
    & "${env:MSBuildPath}\MSBuild.exe" $_ '/t:package' '/p:Configuration=Debug'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell. this is a simple issue that many people encounter.

---

## Delayed Expansion

Make sure your script contains `setlocal enableDelayedExpansion` somewhere before the loop.

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedexpansion

rem script.
```

Then, to make sure batch changes the `%val%` properly, change `%val%` to `!val!`

```
     %MSBuildPath%\MSBuild.exe !VAL! /t:package /p:Configuration=Debug
```

Or this solution that does not require **delayed expansion**

```
     %MSBuildPath%\MSBuild.exe %%i /t:package /p:Configuration=Debug
```

Or the best one:

```
    "%MSBuildPath%\MSBuild.exe" "%%~i" /t:package /p:Configuration=Debug
```

`~` means to dequote.

---

## Starting application

`CALL` is only used when calling a subroutine or another batch script, just remove it.

---

### Final Script

```
FOR /F "delims=" %%i IN ('"powershell . ".\GetSfProjPath.ps1 GetPathToSfProj -rootPath "%ProjectLocationPath%" -solutionName "%SolutionName%""; "') DO (
   "%MSBuildPath%\MSBuild.exe" "%%~i" /t:package /p:Configuration=Debug
)
```

Comment: I've tried just to output results from loop like : `FOR /F "delims=" %%i IN ('"powershell . ".\GetSfProjPath.ps1 GetPathToSfProj -rootPath "%ProjectLocationPath%" -solutionName "%SolutionName%""; "') DO (
   @echo %%~i
)
pause` as result i still get nothing http://imageshack.com/i/pnv1VGwSp

Comment: You don't have the `echo` statement in your image.

Comment: In your photo, you did not have the `echo` statement. Copy my final script and try again.

Comment: You didn't get what I mean :) Instead of exec MSBuild I want to see result of powershell function... just for testing. So I've tried to use ECHO to see result... But it is not working or is it empty... :(

Comment: Okay. https://imageshack.com/i/pnv1VGwSp in this photo, there is NO `echo` command appearing at all. You didn't use the `echo` that's why it's empty

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151257/discussion-between-demo-and-stevefest).